# Net 5 C# Console - VS2019 Build transforms

Tags: c#, configuration, console-application, .net-5, appsettings

I am trying to work out how to do build transforms in VS2019/2022 .Net 5 Console application *without* using environment variables or custom host environment files (ie. hostsettings.json *environment: development* json syntax).  Although the latter if there is no other option.

The environment we use is based on the Visual Studio Configuration Manager Active Solution configuration.  Applications are deployed using a publish profile (.pubxml) and use the *msbuild /p:configuration=* syntax.  There are also some pre- and post- build events which are based on the active configuration.

I have been using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder() for the most part and can access the main appsettings.json,  however, now I would like to add in the appropriate transform part to the filename.  I have not been able to work out how to get ConfigurationBuilder() to get the target environment without setting an environment variable (which I cannot do).

I have also investigated using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder(), and given a hostsettings.json file I can retrieve an environment and then load the appropriate appsettings.target.json file.

However, in this case, I can't work out how to actually access any settings after I call Build().  In ConfigurationBuilder()  I can do something like _iconfig["mysetting"].ToString() or _iconfig.GetConnectionString("name").

In HostBuilder() I have added a .ConfigureAppConfiguration() and can retrieve the section/values that I want - but cannot find any documentation on how to store it or access them later in the code.

I am wondering if anyone has some example code that works in a console app (not written for the web) for .net 5 that retrieves a value out of appsettings.target.json without using environment variables?

Regards.

Comment: note: After posting I did find how to set the launchsettings.json environment variable and can set ConfigurationBuilder to read the custom appsettings, however, this is effectively using an environment variable.  I'd still like to know if it is possible to use HostBuilder().

Comment: Another update. For now I just put a T4 (.tt) template in the root directory of the project that makes a call to EnvDTE to get the Active Configuration name and it generates a new hostsettings.json file containing the correct environment value.